# find spectrum matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left[ \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&b&0&0&0&0\\
c&0&b&0&0&0\\
0&c&0&b&0&0\\
0&0&c&0&b&0\\
0&0&0&c&0&b\\
0&0&0&0&c&0
\end{array} \right]_{n \times n}$.

Why does matrix $A$ have spectrum $\sigma (A) = \left\{ 2\sqrt {bc} \cos \left(\frac{\pi k}{n + 1}\right):k = 1,2,\ldots,n \right\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}(I_n - A_n)$ where $A_n$ is the matrix described above, and let $\psi_n(\lambda) = \det(B_n - \lambda I_n)$ be $B$'s characteristic polynomial. $B_n$ will be a tridiagonal matrix with the the values $-\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{b}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}, -\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{c}}$ on each row.

If we expand $\det(B_n - \lambda I_n)$ by the last row we get
$$\begin{align}
\psi_n(\lambda) &= \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}} - \lambda \right) \psi_{n-1}(\lambda) - \psi_{n-2}(\lambda)
\end{align}$$
and we have a recurrence starting condition that $\psi_1(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}} - \lambda$.

The above recurrence is strikingly similar to the recurrence for the [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $U_n$, which are described by the recurrence:
$$\begin{align}
U_0(x) &= 1 \\
U_1(x) &= 2x \\
U_n(x) &= 2xU_{n-1}(x) - U_{n-2}(x)
\end{align}$$
so if we change variables by setting $2x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}} -\lambda$ and set $\psi_0(x) = 1$ we get the above recurrence:
$$\begin{align}
\psi_0(x) &= 1 \\
\psi_1(x) &= 2x \\
\psi_n(x) &= 2x\psi_{n-1}(x) - \psi_{n-2}(x)
\end{align}$$

It is well-known that the roots of $U_n$ are:
$$x_k = \cos \left( \frac{k}{n+1}\pi \right)$$
which gives us the eigenvalues for $B_n$:
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}} - 2x_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}} - 2\cos \left( \frac{k}{n+1}\pi \right)$$

Now, if $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $B_n$, what will the corresponding eigenvalue $\mu_k$ be for $A_n$? We have:
$$\lambda_k v_k = B_n v_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}\left(I_n - A_n \right)v_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}(v_k - A_nv_k)$$
so $A_nv_k = v_k - \sqrt{bc} \lambda_k v_k = (1 - \sqrt{bc}\lambda_k)v_k$, i.e.
$$\mu_k = 1 - \sqrt{bc}\lambda_k
= 2 \sqrt{bc} \cos \left( \frac{k}{n+1}\pi \right)
$$