# Show convergence of Power method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a symmetric positive definite matrix $A_0 \in R^{n \text{x} n}$ with Cholesky decomposition $A_0 = LL^T$.
How can I show that $A_k$ converges to $diag(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ where $A_k$ is computed as follows where $A_{k-1} = L_k L_k^T$ is the Cholesky factorization of $A_{k-1}$

for k = 1, 2, ...

$A_{k-1} = L_k L_k^T$

$A_k = L_k^TL_k $

end

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about how $A_k$ are computed? For instance, is $A_1 = L^T L$ ? And I can't quite see how to get $A_2$ from that.

Comment: @AnlamK Why not? If $A_0=L_1L_1^T$, $A_2=L_1^TL_1$, etc.

Comment: BTW this is not the power method. It is equivalent to the [QR algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240577/find-spectrum-matrix-a/1242052) applied to $A^{1/2}$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Could you give some hints on how to prove it converges to $diag(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proven (along with similar algorithms) in the paper [Convergence of the LR, QR, and related algorithms by J.H.Wilkinson](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/8/1/77.full.pdf).

Your question simply asks about LR algorithm as applied to positive definite matrices.

The authors provide a rather elementary proof. I'm also including in (picture format) the answer to your question in the simplest case, where the eigenvalues have distinct modulus - that is: $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_2| >\ldots >|\lambda_n|$ and the matrix is full rank (along with another assumption - see the screen shots below).

[image]
[image]
[image]